# Data load from Arena (DMS) to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue-spark

I'm building a unified data platform on the AWS cloud and need to get the necessary information from the Arena document management source system.
Has anyone developed a code or any service for ingesting documents or data from the Arena solution (DMS) to AWS S3?

At first, I considered using the APIs that DMS might have made available for consumption, but I was unable to find a workaround. Please share any tools or experience you have that fit this need.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.